# Getting data from service to another component

Tags: angular

from **component A** where i have list of All users, when i click on **EDIT** I send data with user ID to service and from service to **component B**
 In **service.ts** I create

```
  selectedUser = new Subject<any>();
```

From **component A**

```
this.userService.selectedUser.next(this.user);
```

And in **component B**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.userService.selectedUser.subscribe(
  user => {
    this.user = user;
    console.log(this.user);
  },
  data => {
    if (this.user === undefined) {
      this.addNewUserState = true;
      this.createForm();
    } else {
      this.addNewUserState = false;
      this.addNewUserForm.controls["username"].setValue(this.user.username);
      this.addNewUserForm.controls["firstName"].setValue(this.user.firstName);
    }
  }
)
};
```

On first **DETAIL** click I don't get data, in network tab I get data for the selected user, but `consol.log()` not logged anything
here is preview 
https://ttprivatenew.s3.amazonaws.com/pulse/bozzodj/attachments/11660135/TinyTake10-10-2019-10-00-04.mp4

Comment: the `subscribe` doesn't work like this, it takes an `observer` object or callbacks functions (next, error, complete) respectively so what you need to do here is to merge the callbacks into one

anyways your question is not clear, you mentioned the `console` but your code doesn't have any console functions

Comment: I added console.log()... can you show me example how to merge the callbacks?

Comment: ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.selectedUser.asObservable().subscribe(
            user => {
                this.user = user;
                console.log(this.user);
                if (this.user === undefined) {
                    // CODE
                } else {
                    // CODE
                }
            }
        )
    };

Comment: @Ezzabuzaid thnx, but still same problem is here...

Comment: Can you please use correct syntax, as pointed out by @Ezzabuzaid, and then write down the error that you're getting.

Comment: `this.userService.selectedUser.asObservable().subscribe(
      user => {
        this.user = user;
        console.log(this.user);
      },
      data => {
        if (this.user === undefined) {....} }
    );`    and i dont get any error, only I get data on  second click

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when data is async.

You can either handle it with **`async-await`** or **`promise`**

The below is done using **`async-await`**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.selectedUser.subscribe(async user => {
      this.user = await user;
      console.log(this.user);
    },
    data => {
      if (this.user === undefined) {
        this.addNewUserState = true;
        this.createForm();
      } else {
        this.addNewUserState = false;
        this.addNewUserForm.controls["username"].setValue(this.user.username);
        this.addNewUserForm.controls["firstName"].setValue(this.user.firstName);
      }
    }
  )
};
```

Comment: thnx, I try this, but this not working. The same problem is still there